# Solving a system of rational functions

Tags: abstract-algebra, complex-analysis, rational-functions

Given $c_k \in \mathbb C$ distinct nonzero complex numbers. Is that possible to find a nontrivial solution for $\vec x = (x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n) \in \mathbb C^n$ such that $\vec x$ satisfies the following system of equations $$\frac{6}{c_k} + \sum_{i \ne k} \frac{2}{c_k - c_i} = \sum_{i = 1}^n \frac{1}{c_k - x_i} \forall k = 1, 2, 3, \dots, n$$

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: Can't you just pick any values for all but one of the $x_i$ (as long as we don't divide by zero), and then solve for the last one via $\square=\square+(x-\square)^{-1}$?

Comment: I originally try to solve the following problem: given $h(x) \in \mathbb C[x]$ with $h(x) = \prod_{i = 1}^n (x - c_i)$ ($c_i$ distinct nonzero complex numbers) Can we find a complex polynomial $p(x)$ with degree n such that $$(6h'(x) + xh''(x))p(x) = xh'(x)p'(x)$$